# find maximum in a list in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

i'm writing a prolog code that will find the maximum number in a list , this is my code , it doesn't work , does anyone know where is the wrong

```
max([X],X).
max([H|T], M):-
    max(T , M1),
    T>=M1,
    M is T.
```

Comment: You forgot to tell Prolog what to do in case `T < M1`. But nevertheless this is quite inefficient.

Comment: Your code does work sometimes, like `max([1,2],R).` - at least in SICStus and SWI.